# Maven find property usage

Tags: maven, maven-2

If I define a property in some high level pom.xml under `<properties>` element, and some children poms are using it, is there a way to list them?

Comment: None that I am aware of. But that's definitely an interesting question.

Comment: What do you want to know ? all pom using a specific property or all properties used by each pom ?

Comment: @mmounirou All poms using a specific property.

Comment: if you are on unix based system or has a bash on your window (with cygwin) you can use grep .

Comment: grep '${property-name}' pom.xml */pom.xml */*/pom.xml

Comment: @mmounirou - I guess, but the properties are sometimes evaluated also by satellite assemblies, referenced by `maven-assembly-plugin`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it can be done with IntelliJ - using the "Find references" dialogue.

Too bad maven can't help here.